# Зачем нужен цикл в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Обычно для чего используют перебор элементов в массиве?

Прошу не губить, так как я новичок.

```js
let arr = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Груша"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  alert( arr[i] );
}
```

Comment: Вместо `alert` используйте `console.log`, вам будет удобнее

Comment: Цикл по всему массиву используют, чтобы произвести какие-то действия со всеми элементами массива, получить результат на основе обработки всех элементов массива.. Вроде бы это логично, не так ли?

Comment: Проще говоря цикл нужен, чтобы одновременно изменить все элементы в массиве? Я все правильно понял?

Comment: Ну, например, для вывода элементов массива по очереди, как в вашем коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы проходиться по массиву. Можно его изменять, например

```js
const arr = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Груша"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i] + ' Привет';
}

console.log(arr);
```

Пример, как посчитать сумму элементов в массиве, для этого подойдёт цикл:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; // Массив с числами

let sum = 0; // Переменная, в которой будет высчитываться сумма

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sum = sum + arr[i]; // переменная sum = sum + текущий элемент массива
} // таким образом можно посчитать сумму всех элементов в массиве

console.log(sum);
```

Пример, надо создать функцию, которая возвращает true, если в массиве есть число 5, иначе функция возвращает false:

```js
function thereIsANumberFiveInTheArray(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 5) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

const arrNum5 = [1, 'Привет', 5];
const arrNotNum5 = [1, 'Привет'];

console.log('arrNum5', thereIsANumberFiveInTheArray(arrNum5));
console.log('arrNotNum5', thereIsANumberFiveInTheArray(arrNotNum5));
```

Пример, вывести в консоль только нечетные элементы массива:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] % 2 === 1) {
     console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Перебор нужен для изменения элементов в массиве?

Comment: @Человек нет, это одно из вещей, что можно делать. Самое главное - ты получаешь доступ к элементу массива в цикле и можешь им оперировать. Строить разные условия, например: если значение элемента в массиве больше 5, то прибавить к нему 5, иначе ничего не делать.

Comment: Цикл нужно использовать, когда нам нужно провернуть какие-нибудь манипуляции со всеми элементами в массиве?

Comment: @Человек да, можно и не со всеми, по отдельности, с кем-то делать манипуляции с кем-то нет.

Comment: Если вас это не затруднит, не могли бы вы пожалуйста показать мне пример в цикле массива, когда идет манипуляция с одним элементом,а не со всеми подряд, как в ваших примерах выше.

Comment: @Человек, поменяй `i++` на `i+=2` и получишь сумму только элементов на четных местах

Comment: @Михаил Камахин, благодарю за старание и помощь.